# Error when returning a HttpResponse from a Django Helper Function

Tags: ajax, django, methods, django-views, dry

I have the below code in a basic Django view, which creates a new product and I am using AJAX to filter a list of industries. I would like to move the ajax processing code into a separate method but I am getting that the view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Can anyone recommend the way to separate it out safely? I have other views that use the exact logic.

```
def new_instrument(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.get('typeis') =='industry':
            print('Now loading industries')
            sectorid = int(request.GET.get('sector_is'))
            sector = models.SecSectorMaster.objects.filter(pk=sectorid).order_by('sectorname')
            industries = models.SecIndustryMaster.objects.filter(sectorid=sector).order_by('industryname')
            industry_dict = {}
            for this_i in industries:
                industry_dict[this_i.industryid] = this_i.industryname
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(industry_dict),
                content_type="application/json"
            )**
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mainform= forms.EditInstrumentForm(sector,industrygroup,industries,request.POST,prefix="main")
        if mainform.is_valid():
            security = mainform.save()
            selectid = security.pk           
            return redirect('instrumentsapp.views.security_list')
        else:
            return render(request, 'instrumentsapp/edit_instrument.html', {'mainform': mainform}) 
    else:
        mainform = forms.EditInstrumentForm(prefix="main")
        return render(request, 'instrumentsapp/edit_instrument.html', {'mainform': mainform})
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: Upon firing the ajax function on the page and this here view is called

Comment: What happens if the request method is Ajax but does typeis != 'industry'?

Comment: Not created yet, ie the Ajax only has the one typeis value.  I have confirmed from the request.GET that the typeis is set correctly. The page should proceed to ignore the ajax block and load the form normally. To be clear, the page as shown here works, its when I try to move the ajax block in a separate method altogether that it throws the httpresponse error

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your view and use JsonResponse directly, and you should return a response if your test fail, this might be your issue since they told you that it returned None instead. I believe you should write something like this

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_industry(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.get('typeis') =='industry':
            print('Now loading industries')
            sectorid = int(request.GET.get('sector_is'))
            sector = models.SecSectorMaster.objects.filter(pk=sectorid).order_by('sectorname')
            industries = models.SecIndustryMaster.objects.filter(sectorid=sector).order_by('industryname')
            industry_dict = {}
            for this_i in industries:
                industry_dict[this_i.industryid] = this_i.industryname
            return JsonResponse(industry_dict)
        return JsonResponse({'industry': None})
```

Comment: thank you very much, let me see about JsonResponse. If I may ask, why have you used two return  statements?

Comment: Yeah let me know how it goes for you. I added another returned statement to handle the case where your if == 'industry' fail so you can still have a response in your Ajax request and handle it how you want in your js (or wherever you call the view from) if this happens.